# Telerik MVC - View not picking up the data from Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm starting with Telerik and got this issue. The grid is parsed to the expected location: `localhost:.../Dashboard/Dashboard` not throwing any exception, however it is EMPTY. Json picks up correctly the data from my ViewModel and is returned properly in `localhost:.../Dashboard/ChartTable`. For some reason the View does not read this Json. How would I go about this?

**Edit**

I digged Telerik upside down for errors, and below suggestions just reinforced me that the code in View in Controller were ok. The issue was that in one of the ViewModel fields (not mentioned in the sample code here) my Json returned NaN - which is not valid in Json. So I should not have said that Json picked up the date correctly. It was a very good learning to get this error.

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<PriceBench.ViewModels.CompsSnapshotVM>

<div id="div1">

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(200).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.MatchCount).Width(300).Title("Count");
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ChartTable", "Dashboard"))
        )
)
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ChartTable([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    DataSourceResult result = _dashRepo.GetCompsSnapshotVM().ToDataSourceResult(request);

    return Json(result);
}

public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the edit, the problem was that Json had a NaN in one of the ViewModel fields. NaN is not allowed in Json and it will block Telerik from displaying the view correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're binding your grid to the View's model and trying to use AJAX at the same time.. just change your grid to this.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PriceBench.ViewModels.CompsSnapshotVM>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(200).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.MatchCount).Width(300).Title("Count");
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ChartTable", "Dashboard"))
        )
)
```

which just tells the grid what the model type is.  or pass in the data you want to bind the grid to when you call the view the first time.

you probably want to remove the `.ServerOperation(false)` part too from your datasource settings

Edit.

try adding `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` to your return.

```
public ActionResult ChartTable([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var result = _dashRepo.GetCompsSnapshotVM().ToDataSourceResult(request);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: Thank you JamieD77, I'm checking, but this is still not giving me any change. Something is strange, because the code I posted had worked for me previously... I have no clue what I messed up.

Comment: This helped me to further understand that the issue was not with my Controller or View. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While Working with kendo grid in ASP.NET MVC we have couple of option.

1. AutoBind(): If set to false the widget will not bind to the data source during initialization. In this case data binding will occur when the change event of the data source is fired. By default the widget will bind to the data source specified in the configuration.
2. GetType(HttpVerbs.Get):if you want to get data on HTTP GET.
3. ServerOperation(bool) : to enable or disable server operations.
4. Pager : To implement pager
5. Page Size  :if pager is implemented use page size for for paging.

so your grid will be like this.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PriceBench.ViewModels.CompsSnapshotVM>()
    .Name("grid")
    .AutoBind() //if you are using AutoBind
  //If you want to implement Pager
     .Pageable(pager => pager
                    .PageSizes(true)                    
                    .Info(true)
                    .PreviousNext(true)                    
                )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(200).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.MatchCount).Width(300).Title("Count");
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)      
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ChartTable", "Dashboard"))            
        )
)
```

if you want to use HTTP GET it will be like this.

```
.Read(read => read.Action("ChartTable", "Dashboard").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
```

I am not sure how you are making call to bind this grid. if you can tell me I can suggest you according to that.

ref

- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid?
- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration
- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/server-binding

let me know how it worked for you.

This Grid worked for me:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UserViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Username).Width(150).Title("User Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Role).Width(100).ClientTemplate("#=Role.RoleName#").Filterable(false).Width(80).Sortable(false);       
    })        
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()        
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()               
        .PageSize(10)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);            
            model.Field(p => p.Role).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultCategory"] as UserRole);
        }
        )


                .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllUser", "Administration"))

    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think these are additional options or retyping the defaults. I tried these, but this does not serve the problem :(

Comment: Where would you look for the binds to the grid? Everything should be happening only in the Controller and View. The helper metod GetCompsSnapshotVM is more complex and works fine according to me, because the json is passed to the ChartTable action method.

Comment: can you let me know how you are making calls to your controller ?

Comment: I believe the call to the controller is made in read.Action in the View as posted above, but if you have some other suggestion, just let me know where to look for it?

Comment: if you are not using AutoBind and .ServerOperation(false) then how the grid will know it has to get the data. there should be some triggering point. i think you should try AutoBind option.

Comment: can you check your developer tool or console for any errors?

Comment: I tried these options, but it did not work for me. I'm starting to think there might be some issues with imports to Telerik or something else.

Comment: Thank you, I upvote your comment as it help me to understand the issue was not with my controller or view.